# In supabase's flutter sdk, how do I filter a stream using something like .contains("group_members", [my_uid])?

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

In supabase's flutter sdk, how do I filter a stream using something like

```
.contains("group_members", [my_uid])
```

how do I achieve something like this?

I tried adding

```
.contains("group_members", [my_uid])
```

but it doesn't work like it does with select()

Answer (score 0):

supabaes_flutter does not yet support the usecase, but we are super close to supporting this feature. Once added, you will be able to do something like this:

```dart
supabase.from('table').stream(primaryKey: ['id']).in_('name', ['Andy', 'Santiago', 'Holt'])
```

You can watch the following PR for the progress of this feature
https://github.com/supabase/supabase-dart/pull/191

### Edit 2024/01/08

It has landed with `inFilter` as the final filter name.

```dart
supabase.from('table').stream(primaryKey: ['id']).inFilter('name', ['Andy', 'Santiago', 'Holt'])
```

Comment: Also, how can I use inFilter where the column type is text[]? Is there some kind of .arrayContains query I can use in flutter supabase? How can I achieve something like arrayContains?

Comment: @Manbus Not for realtime. For the regular API, you can use `contains` https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/contains